# menu tab color should remain same as before page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a menu tab which is made of `<ul>` & `<li>` tags.
I have set a particular colour on its click, but as soon as the page refreshes the link colour changes to default.
I want to keep the link colour as it was before page refresh.

Comment: There could be something in the javascript code that changes the color. It will be helpful for the people if you show that code.

Answer (score 1):

try to put some flag in session.Then apply the color by getting from the session.When the page is refreshed you can get the value from session

or you can use the local storage

Answer (score 0):

Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) to store the color.So you can retrieve later.

// Save data to a the current session's store

```
sessionStorage.setItem("color", "red");
```